# Dialogflow how to merge couple of agents in one

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am new in [DialogFlow](https://console.dialogflow.com/api-client/) , I started to create agent, and started from smaltalk scratch. The question is how can I attach more pre-build agents like alarm and app-management, and maybe currency-converter into newly created one?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [import prebuilt agents](https://dialogflow.com/docs/prebuilt-agents) into your existing agent to expand your agent's ability to respond to a variety of inputs.  Importing will add intents and entities to your existing agent, expanding its functionality and will not remove or alter any existing intents, entities or functions like small talk.

If you have another Dialogflow agent you'd like to "merge" into another agent you can [export one agent and import it into another](https://dialogflow.com/docs/agents#export_and_import) to "merge" the two agent's functionalities.  Please note that this may result in unexpected behavior and is not recommended as a development technique.

Answer (score 2):

[Import prebuilt agent](https://dialogflow.com/docs/agents/prebuilt-smalltalk) says:

> Importing a Prebuilt Agent creates a new agent. If you want to include Prebuilt Agent functionality into an existing agent, you'll need to move the intents from the newly created Prebuilt Agent into your existing agent.

So, create a new project, select and move all the intents created in the new agent to the agent you require.

Answer (score 0):

Last week I faced a similar issue where we were merging Prebuilt -SmallTalk Intents to a newly created Dialogflow Agent. Surprisingly custom Intents added in Agent stops working but Smalltalk Intents keeps working. However, they keep working on Dialogflow console Web Agent but if we call service from our code it always replied with Default Fallback Intent.
This happens when you copy/import/clone/export Prebuilt Intents.

I looked at this issue almost a day and finally figured out that the issue is with language sent in your API request.  I was sending en-US as a language code. At the moment you add Prebuilt agents it stops working with language en-US. This is weird behavior as the same Agent works fine with en-US if we do not add any Prebuilt Intents.

The solution is to send language code - "en" only and Custom Intent will work fine.

That solution clicked me when I used curl command as copied from Dialogflow console web Testing of my Agent -- as it worked I compared request to the request sent by Java code and found a difference in language code.

Probably its some Integration issue in DialogFlow.